# HTML Submit button returns 'HTTP405' error when clicked

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am currently running my website on a local live server via VisualStudio. 
I want my HTML contact form (written in index.html file) to send mail using PHPMailer (written in contact-form-handler.php) when the 'SUBMIT' button in my HTML form is clicked.

When I click the button, I am brought to a page that says
'This Page isn't working HTTP 405'.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it please.

**index.html:**

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
       <label for="name">NAME</label>
       <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required>
       <label for="mob">MOBILE NUMBER</label>
       <input id="mob" type="text" name="mob" required>
       <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
       <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
       <label for="message">MESSAGE</label>
       <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message" required></textarea>
       <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**contact-form-handler.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '587';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Username = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';

    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->addAddress= 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Test';
    $mail->Body= '<h1> name:'.$_POST['name'].'<br> Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br> Mobile: '.$_POST['mob'].'<br> message: '.$_POST['message'].'</h1>';

    if(!$mail->send()){
        $result="something went wrong. Please try again."; 
    }
    else{
        $result="Success!"
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: As your `action=""` attribute is empty you are running this page again when you press the submit. So where is the code in this page?

Comment: if I amend it to: 
action="contact-form-handler.php"

I face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

An [HTTP 405 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) means that you have requested a resource using an unsupported method, so for some reason your web server is not allowing a POST request to your endpoint. You could try changing your form tag to:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="get" action="">
```

This is not a great solution - the better way would be to fix your server config to allow the POST method.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: By changing your form tag? As for altering your web server, I can't tell you; you would need to read the documentation and inspect the config of your web server, whatever you're using.

Answer (score -1):

I'd comment under you question but I can't. @RiggsFolly is right and you have to place to `action` attribute your php file because the form have to send it to your `contact-form-handler.php`. Be sure that you don't use php code in your `index.html` because it won't work. It'd be nice if you add to your question code from `contact-form-handler.php`, may be it can help us to find out what is going wrong

Comment: I have added my php file to show what's going on in there